# How to add file into state on React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a formdata object. I'm moving this into a reducer with redux. Then can I define the file contained in this formData into INITIAL_STATE?

```
var INITIAL_STATE = { stepOneInformation: {} }
```

REDUCER

```
case STEP_ONE_SET_DATA:    
        const data = {
            file : action.value.get('file'),
            aboutMe : action.value.get('aboutMe'),
            title : null
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            stepOneInformation: data
        }
```

I defined the file in the formdata object to the data variable parameter. But the file object looks blank when reading the state

Comment: debug - stick a `console.log(action.value.get(file))` in your reducer and then open the console when performing the thing that triggers the action. The code you've shown itself is fine, it's the code you haven't shown where the problem is.

Comment: @Adam there is no problem in that part. The data variable is full. When reading the initial state in local storage in componentDidMount, the following result appears. aboutMe: "test", file: {}, title: null. empty file variable

Comment: `When reading the initial state` - but you didn't set the file object as part of your initial state - you set it in response to an action?

Comment: When I change the file variable to blob type in the reducer, I can read it in componentDidMount. But I can read it as an empty object as a file. @Adam

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to read your initial state to get the updated data, because it is stored in the state variable of the store. It's also a bad practice to get data directly from the state, use `mapStateToProps` instead